# Не могу изменить настройки mariadb 10.5

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mariadb

На сервере с centos 7.9 была древняя mariadb 5.5.68
Вчера удалил её и установил новую mariadb 10.5.8
Вижу, что обычного файла с настройками my.cnf уже нет, а вместо него, насколько я понял настройки хранятся в папке `/etc/my.cnf.d` Открываю файл `server.cnf` и пытаюсь редактировать его:

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]


# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

max_connections=3985

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.5 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.5]
```

Я указал max_connections=3985 после чего пробовал перезагружать mariadb.service и даже делал reboot сервера. Ничего не помогает - после перезагрузки я вбиваю запрос

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections"
```

но неизменно получаю:

```
Variable_name     Value
max_connections   151
```

Я пробовал указывать max_connections=3985 в разных секциях [mariadb] [mariadb-10.5] [server] и т.д.
Но max_connections всё равно остаётся 151.
Может я вообще не там пытаюсь указывать настройки? Или что-то делаю не так? Подскажите.

Comment: А как именно вы установили новую mariadb?